# regular expression allow dot and special caracters in middle of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex that match a specific pattern:

```
\d[\.]?[\s]?(\w+[\s]?)+\d+((\.|\,)\d{2,3})
```

It matches the following inputs perfectly:

```
1 XXX XXX   0,34
1 X5X XXX   0,34
```

My problem comes if there is a dot `.` or another special character like `%` like

```
1 XX. 5 XXX 0,34
1 XXX 4% XX 0,34
```

How could allow the regex to find those kind of characters?

Comment: How do you define *special characters*?

Comment: characters like '$%&#@€...." I am trying to parse what an ocr returns to me, and sometimes it returns this kind of things instead of letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match that pattern and you don't need the capturing groups, you could use an optional character class `[.%]?` after matching a word char.

To match them when they are not necessarily at the end, use `[\w.%]+`

You can omit the square brackets around the `[\s]` and write `(\.|\,)` as `[.,]`

Repeating a capturing group will capture the value of the last iteraration, so you might turn that into a non capturing group `(?:`

```
\d\s?(?:\w+[.%]?\s)+\d+[.,]\d{2,3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U3Pab1/1)

With the capturing groups:

```
\d\s?(\w+[.%]?\s)+\d+(([.,])\d{2,3})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU2NVa/1)

Comment: wow, thanks you really gave to me a string to pull. I need in fact capture the group, but a you said only gets me the last group, so I have to struggle a bit more in order to capture all the groups among the numbers. I will give the answer as correc, since you solve my first issue